# Pass data from JQuery on click function to PHP server?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm calling a REST Server via a simple function:

```
$(document).on('click', '#test', function(e){   
    e.preventDefault();
    var name = $(this).data('name'); 
    var path = $(this).data('path');  
    window.location = "http://localhost:80/server/api/v1/files/" + name;        
});
```

How can I pass aditional data (eg. the path) to my server so that I would be able to grab it in the php request?

```
public function show($request, $response, $args)
{ 
  // $request contains the path
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in Jquery you can you use ajax

```
$(document).on('click', '#test', function(e){   
    e.preventDefault();
    var name = $(this).data('name'); 
    var path = $(this).data('path');   
    $.ajax({
        'url' : 'http://localhost:80/server/api/v1/files/',
        'method' : 'POST',
        'data' : {
            'name' : name,
            'path' : path
        },
        success(function(data){
            console.log("Sent data");
        })
    });
});
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Is it possibly to achieve the same without ajax?

Comment: Yes you can pass the parameters as args

Comment: Okay, that would be a possibility but makes no sense because it violates REST best practices in my opinion.

Comment: Yes it does violate REST practices